# A question in Folland's book on Real Analysis

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, sobolev-spaces, fourier-transform, fractional-sobolev-spaces

I came across the following Theorem in Folland's book (Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and their application), Theorem 8.33

1. Where do we use the fact that $f$ is continuous in this proof?
2. Why can't we state a similar theorem for $\mathbb{T}^n$ without using Sobolev space?

[image]

Comment: It's not just continuous, it's absolutely continuous, which allows you to say something about $f'$.

Comment: Which one of Folland's books? He has written more than one.